# How can I get the "Archive Name" (in Edit Scheme/Archive/Archive Name) dynamically with the CFBundleShortVersionString in suffix?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, scheme, xcode8

With the same way that ( $(PRODUCT_NAME), $(EXECUTABLE_NAME), $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) ), is it possible to get the executable name of the file (in the Info.plist) with the version number (for example $VERSION or something like this) ?

For now, I have $(TARGET_NAME), I would like to add the version number (CFBundleShortVersionString). example : Name_of_the_App_v1.45.ipa

Changing the "product name" like in the following picture doesn't work :
[image]

For info, I use that script to increment automatically the build and the version in "Build Phases/Run Script".

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf build

Build=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
Build=$(($Build + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $Build" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"

Version=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
Version=$(echo "scale=2; $Version + 0.01" | bc)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $Version" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

The only thing that change the name of the ipa archive is in the section "Edit Scheme/Archive/Archive name" that takes by default the name of the Scheme. So You have to change the Archive name or directly change the value of the Scheme if you want to see that value in the name ipa.
[image]

How can I modify dynamically that Archive name, to add the CFBundleShortVersionString in suffix directly in the Run Script section or anywhere else 
?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by adding a User-Defined Build-Setting to your Target. Click Project -> Targetname -> Build-Settings -> Plus-Button -> Name: APP_VERSION, Value: 1.0.0. The newly defined build-setting is then available as preprocessor-variable $(APP_VERSION) in your Info.plist.

For clarity, you should also set your CFBundleShortVersionString to that variable, so the two Info.plist-Entries will always contain the same version-string.

Comment: Solution very interesting, but my problem is that I use a script that increments automatically the build and the version.  
I put the code of the script in the orignal question to be more clear.

Comment: I don't think I can use both ?

Comment: Interesting. Try updating APP_VERSION in that script and check if the new contents get applied in Info.plist. APP_VERSION="$Version"

Comment: It is a pity, I just tested everything, and the problem is that the Product Name section doesn't change the name of the ipa. The only thing that change it, is the "archive name" in the Edit Scheme/Archive/Archive name and it takes by default the value of the name of the Scheme. If fact the only way to change the name of the ipa, is to change that value, or change the name of the scheme. Is there anyway to change the name of the Scheme dynamically by adding it the CFBundleShortVersionString in suffix ?

Comment: Well the name of the executable file and the name of the IPA are 2 different things. To automatically control the naming of a IPA file, you would have to do command line builds with xcodebuild clean build archive and xcodebuild -exportArchive. See man xcodebuild. Alternatively you can consider using a CI system like Jenkins, which can take care of the ipa naming for you